# R kriging in QGIS

Tags: r, installation, windows, qgis-processing, kriging

I'm trying to work with the R Kriging script in QGIS (processing toolbox). I have installed R before directly to C:. I also have installed the packages raster, rgdal, sp and automap. When I'm starting the script I always get the following message:

> options("repos"="http://cran.at.r-project.org/")
>   .libPaths("C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library")
>   tryCatch(find.package("automap"), error=function(e) install.packages("automap", dependencies=TRUE))
>   [1] "C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/automap"
>   tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
>   [1] "C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/raster"
>   tryCatch(find.package("rgdal"), error=function(e) install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE))
>   [1] "C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/rgdal"
>   tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
>   [1] "C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/raster"
>   library("raster")
>   Fehler: Paket 'sp' benötigt von 'raster' nicht gefunden

Answer (score 2):

Use the corrected script [Bug report #14608: Processing: Kriging rscripts/Kriging.rsx Automap problem and correction](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14608), accepted in the master ([Kriging.rsx](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/rscripts/Kriging.rsx))

It is not a problem of QGIS, it is a problem with you R packages installation.

1) Processing use the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute directly the R commands
2) it use an intermediate file named  /.../.qgis2/processing/processing_script.r and the results or errors in the file /.../.qgis2/processing/processing_script.r.Rout

The interface

[image]

If you look at the resulting processing_script.r, it is possible to see that it uses `rgdal` to open the file and save the resulting files, transformed by `raster`

```
...
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
Layer = readOGR("path to",layer="Leontot") -> the chosen file
Field="DIP_DIR" -> the chosen field 
by=100 -> the mesh size
....
kriging_result = autoKrige(A~1, Mesure,  Grille,model=c("Cir","Lin","Bes","Wav","Hol","Leg","Per","Pen","Mat","Exc","Spl","Ste"))
prediction = raster(kriging_result$krige_output)
Output<-prediction
writeRaster(Output,"/var/folders/k9/7s3l5fvd5g1dy31b6sms18fr0000gn/T/processinga3894c34cc084250849b9dba9fe06856/f61b07d41ae54f72bb8d4e1298939fe4/Output.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Threfore:

1. you can examine the error in the file /.../.qgis2/processing/processing_script.r.Rout
2. or you can directly use R or [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) to execute this file and control the errors (why `raster` cannot find `sp`)

   R processing_script.r

#### New

> as.factor(LayerField) : Objekt LayerField nicht gefunden Ausführung angehalten = as.factor(LayerField): object LayerField not found execution suspended

You should not modify the original processing_script.r script but run it in R.

The correct command is

```
Y<-as.factor(Layer[[Field]])
```

If I use [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) to control the script:

```
Layer = readOGR("path_of",layer="sud_for_automap")
# the field chosen in the interface (Field) 
Field="DIP_DIR"
# the values in the field
Layer[[Field]]
[1] 156 154 173 158 163 160 147 160 185 185 160 160 160 165 155 162 164 154 163 165  
[21] 160 162 184 180 175 168 170 172 164 168 165 178 152 175 169 173 165 187 168 168
 ....
```

It is the same as

```
 Layer$DIP_DIR
 [1] 156 154 173 158 163 160 147 160 185 185 160 160 160 165 155 162 164 154 163 165
 [21] 160 162 184 180 175 168 170 172 164 168 165 178 152 175 169 173 165 187 168 168
 .....
```

Comment: So I changed the library folder to "C:\Users\xxxx\.qgis2\processing\rlibs" and the script works...but unfortunately with another error:                             

"......RPLOTS.html.png")
library(automap)
library(raster)
Y
Fehler in as.factor(LayerField) : Objekt 'LayerField' nicht gefunden
Ausführung angehalten
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Output
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm"

Comment: Look above ----